# Evaluation strategy of haskell

Tags: haskell, evaluation

If I have these functions:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add a b = a+b


map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

When I call `map (add 1) [1,2,3]` the output is `[2,3,4]` but how does the evaluation of Haskell work in this case?

My ideas:

It matches with the second pattern because map is a function and [1,2,3] a list.

Then we would have:

```
map (add 1) [1,2,3]
= add 1 : map add [2,3]
= add 1 : add 2 : map add [3]
= add 1 : add 2 : add 3 : map add []
= add 1 : add 2 : add 3 : []
```

However this cannot be true. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Why can’t that be true? That’s exactly what happens. (Except it’s `add 1 1`, `add 1 2`, and `add 1 3`.)

Comment: Oh I forgot the x in every row, so i would have add 1 1 : add 1 2 : add 1 3 : []. Then it's making sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`add 1` is the unary function `f`, not `add`.  So you end up with the following.

```
map (add 1) [1,2,3]
    == add 1 1 : map (add 1) [2,3]
    == add 1 1 : add 1 2 : map (add 1) [3]
    == add 1 1 : add 1 2 : add 1 3 : map (add 1) []
    == 2 : 3 : 4 : []
    == [2,3,4]
```